# Utilisation de "qui" et "que"

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

Je ne sais pas quand je dois utiliser *qui* ou *que* pour parler du sujet.

Il y a toujours deux exemples pour moi :

> 1. Alice que j'aime beaucoup.
> 2. Le voisin qui est très important pour moi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De façon générale :

- *que* introduit une proposition subordonnée relative dans laquelle l’antécédent joue le rôle *d’objet direct*.
- *qui* introduit une proposition subordonnée relative dans laquelle l’antécédent joue le rôle de *sujet*.

Quelques exemples d'utilisation de ***que*** :

- Dans la proposition subordonnée du premier exemple donné dans question :

  > Alice *que j'aime beaucoup*.

  *Alice* est objet direct du verbe *aimer*. La proposition subordonnée seule s'écrirait : « J'<sup>*(sujet)*</sup> aime beaucoup Alice<sup>*(**objet**)*</sup>. »
- Autre exemple :

  > Le stylo *que tu prends dans tes mains* est rouge.

  *Le stylo* est objet direct du verbe *prendre* dans la subordonnée : « Tu<sup>*(sujet)*</sup> prends le stylo<sup>*(**objet**)*</sup> dans tes mains. »

Quelques exemples d'utilisation de ***qui*** :

- Dans la proposition subordonnée du deuxième exemple donné dans la question :

  > Le voisin *qui est très important pour moi*.

  *le voisin* est sujet du verbe *être*. La proposition subordonnée seule s'écrirait : « Le voisin<sup>*(**sujet**)*</sup> est très important pour moi. »
- Autre exemple :

  > La voiture *qui dépasse le camion* roule trop vite.

  *La voiture* est le sujet du verbe *dépasser* dans la subordonnée : « La voiture<sup>*(**sujet**)*</sup> dépasse le camion<sup>*(objet)*</sup>. »

Comment: vous pouvez donner moi quelque plus d'exemple!!

Comment: J'en ai rajouté deux.

Answer (score 2):

I think the English translations of `que` and `qui` (following the context of your question) describe the difference between these two words very well:

- `que` is used for **making a relationship** between the subject (**e.g.**: `Alice`) and a statement (**e.g.**: `j'aime beaucoup`), and **refers to** the subject. 
  Considering your context, the English translation of `que` is **`whom`**. 
  **The English translation of the 1st example you provided would be:**

> *Alice `whom` I like very much.*

- `qui` is used for **describing** the subject (e.g.: `Le voisin`). 
  Considering the context of the question, the English translation of `qui` is **`who`**.
  **The English translation of the 2nd example you provided would be:**

> *The neighbor `who` is very important to me.*

---

Je pense que les traductions de `que` et `qui` en anglais (tout en considérant le contexte de la question posée) décrivent bien la différence entre ces deux mots:

- `que` est utilisé pour **faire une relation** entre le sujet (**ex**: `Alice`) et une proposition (**ex**: `j'aime beaucoup`), et **fait référence** au sujet.
  En prenant en compte le contexte de la question, la traduction de `que` en anglais est **`whom`**.
  **La traduction anglaise du 1er exemple fourni serait:**

> *Alice `whom` I like very much.*

- `qui` est utilisé pour décrire le sujet (ex: `Le voisin`). 
  En prenant en compte le contexte de la question, la traduction de `qui` en anglais est **`who`**.
  **La traduction anglaise du 2ème exemple fourni serait:**

> *The neighbor `who` is very important to me.*

Comment: Il me semble que cette comparaison avec l'anglais rend les choses encore plus confuses, *whom* étant de moins en moins utilisé et aussi parce qu'elle ne marche qu'avec les personnes.

Comment: Par ailleurs, l’antécédent n'est pas forcément sujet dans la proposition principale. Exemple: *J'ai eu une pensée pour Alice que j'aime beaucoup*.