# Comment conjuguer le verbe dans une subordonnée introduite par « que » ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, accord, subordonnées

Je bloque quant à l'usage de cette phrase :

> On comprend mieux l'effervescence que **doit** subir ces hommes de science.

On dit bien *doit* et non pas *doivent* ?

Answer (score 8):

Ce sont *les hommes de science*, au pluriel, qui subissent (pluriel) l'effervescence, donc on accorde, et on dit *doivent*.

Answer (score 5):

Le verbe s'accordant avec le sujet, on a bien *doivent* dans le cas que tu cites.

J'ai mis en évidence les verbes avec leur sujet dans ces deux variantes :

> On comprend mieux l'effervescence que **doivent** subir **ces hommes de science**.
>
> On comprend mieux **l'effervescence** qui **doit** s'exercer sur ces hommes de science.

La différence se situant bien sûr entre les pronoms *qui* (sujet) et *que* (objet).

---

Note : [Cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/utilisation-de-qui-et-que) peut éventuellement t'intéresser aussi.