# Quand écrire « quant » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, conjonctions

On utilise souvent ***quand***, pour poser des questions, ou introduire des propositions subordonnées en rapport avec le temps :

> J'étais dehors quand c'est arrivé.
>   Quand est-ce que tu viendras ?
>   Je l'ai fait quand tu dormais.

Et pourtant, on [trouve](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/3255/1514) [parfois](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/332/1514) ***quant*** écrit avec un *t* :

> Quant à l'usage courant …
>   Je bloque quant à l'usage de cette phrase …

Quelle différence entre ces deux conjonctions ?

Comment: Note que l'on entend le "t" quand même... "quan - ta ..." facile, non?

Comment: @AlexisWilke : Oui, mais on l'entend tout autant dans « Quan(d) - t - est-ce que… », donc ça ne suffit pas à les différencier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si on peut remplacer ***quand*** par ***lorsque***, *à quel moment* ¹, ou *pendant que*, alors on l'écrit avec un *d*. C'est de loin la forme la plus courante.

> J'étais dehors *lorsque* c'est arrivé.
>   *À quel moment* est-ce que tu viendras ?
>   Je l'ai fait *pendant que* tu dormais.

L'autre forme ne s'utilise que dans la locution² ***quant à***, qui signifie « en ce qui concerne », ou « au sujet de » :

> *En ce qui concerne* l'usage courant…
>   Je bloque *au sujet de* cette phrase…

**En règle générale**, *quand* n'est **jamais** suivi de la préposition *à*, et on peut l'écrire toujours avec un *d*, sauf dans *quant à*, où on l'écrit avec un *t*.

¹ ou *au moment où*
² et cette locution prend le rôle d'une *préposition*, pour ceux que la grammaire amuse.

---

Quant à « quand à », c'est souvent l'expression d'un style littéraire où se plaisent les inversions : quand à trop faire le malin on tombe dans le ravin, on ne sait plus où l'on en est ; ou quand, à dessein, la conjonction est directement suivie d'une incise.

Pour d'autres façons de se mélanger les pinceaux, voir [ici pour « qu'en »](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-15842.php), et [là pour « tant qu'à »](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1645).

Answer (score 3):

**Quand** : *when*
**Quant** : *regarding*

Answer (score 3):

La conjonction *quant*, avec un *t*, apparait uniquement dans la locution *quant à* (ou *quant aux* au pluriel), qui joue le rôle d'une préposition. On introduit ainsi des noms ou des infinitifs. Une locution synonyme est « en ce qui concerne ».

Exemple d'utilisation :

> Quant à lui, il fait des crêpes.