# Can you change "que" to "qui" in "ce que seraient mes pensées"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, démonstratifs

The question is on the highlighted *ce que* clause found in this passage from Camus's The Stranger.

> Pendant tout le jour, il y avait mon pourvoi. Je crois que j’ai tiré le meilleur parti de cette idée. Je calculais mes effets et j’obtenais de mes réflexions le meilleur rendement. Je prenais toujours la plus mauvaise supposition : mon pourvoi était rejeté. « Eh bien, je mourrai donc. » Plus tôt que d’autres, c’était évident. Mais tout le monde sait que la vie ne vaut pas la peine d’être vécue. Dans le fond, je n’ignorais pas que mourir à trente ans ou à soixante-dix ans importe peu puisque, naturellement, dans les deux cas, d’autres hommes et d’autres femmes vivront, et cela pendant des milliers d’années. Rien n’était plus clair, en somme. C’était toujours moi qui mourrais, que ce soit maintenant ou dans vingt ans. À ce moment, ce qui me gênait un peu dans mon raisonnement, c’était ce bond terrible que je sentais en moi à la pensée de vingt ans de vie à venir. Mais je n’avais qu’à l’étouffer en imaginant **ce que seraient mes pensées** dans vingt ans quand il me faudrait quand même en venir là. Du moment qu’on meurt, comment et quand, cela n’importe pas, c’était évident. Donc (et le difficile c’était de ne pas perdre de vue tout ce que ce « donc » représentait de raisonnements), donc, je devais accepter le rejet de mon pourvoi.

**QUESTION**

Without changing the meaning and without saying something ungrammatical, could we replace the clause with:

1. *ce qui seraient mes pensées*
2. *ce qui serait mes pensées*

**BACKGROUND**

The idea behind 1 is that, if *mes pensées* is the subject of the clause then *ce qui* or *ce que* is the so-called predicate complement (i.e. the same thing as *a teacher* in *he is a teacher*). In this case, should or can the complement be the same case as the subject, viz. nominative?  But then French has *c'est moi* (and people get into heated debates on *it's me* vs. *it's I*).

The idea behind 2 is that here *ce qui* would be the subject and *mes pensées* the complement.  This seems unlikely if French works like English, in which you say *who are they?* and not *who is they?*  That is to say, the interrogative pronoun does not seem to figure as subject in this type of clauses, at least not in English.

Comment: non, on ne peut pas remplacer. ce que seraient mes pensées => elles seront quoi (mauvais français) ? c'est une chose, pas une personne.

Comment: _La pomme qui tombe._ ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/qui/65685/difficulte)).

Comment: Diffrence between "qui" and "que" applies to "ce qui" "ce que". See [this post](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/3251/358), "ce que" is object (of imaginant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ce qui" and "ce que" are relative pronouns like "qui" and "que"; they introduce a subordinate clause. The choice between the two depends on the grammatical role, subject or direct object, that the relative pronoun has in the subordinate clause.

> Mais je n’avais qu’à l’étouffer en imaginant ce que seraient mes pensées dans vingt ans quand il me faudrait quand même en venir là.

In writing this sentence the author has made the entire clause "*ce que seraient mes pensées*" object of *imaginant*. It is very difficult here to consider the relative pronoun as a subject to  *seraient", it can be seen as a predicative nominal (*attribut*) to "mes pensées". "Ce qui" would sound awkward to a French ear here.

To be able to use "ce qui" you'd have to rephrase the sentence so that the relative pronoun would become subject of a verb.

- Not changing the verb of the relative clause:

> Mais je n’avais qu’à l’étouffer en imaginant ce qui serait dans mes pensées dans vingt ans quand il me faudrait quand même en venir là.

Introducing "dans" definitely makes "ce qui" subject of "serait"; "mes pensées" becoming an adverbial phrase of place.

- Using a different verb in the relative clause:

> Mais je n’avais qu’à l’étouffer en imaginant ce qui occuperait mes pensées dans vingt ans quand il me faudrait quand même en venir là.

"ce qui" has become subject of occuperait.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write “ce qui serait dans mes pensées”, not “ce qui seraient dans mes pensées”. Same for the other example.

Comment: @ Et oui bien sûr...., Merci.

Comment: I presume that your answer would be the same even if the clause was independent?  I.e. *Ce qui seraient mes pensées* would be bad French?

Comment: @Catomic We can't really have a sentence that stands by itself, weexpect something that in a way defines "ce qui" or "ce que". « Ce que seraient mes pensées.. » is an unfinished sentence, « Ce que seraient mes pensées dans vingt ans, je ne peux l'imaginer.  » « Ce qui seraient dans mes pensées dans vingt ans, je ne peux l'imaginer ».

Comment: @Catomic Left you a message in chat.

Comment: Ah! We have *qu'est-ce que* and all those complex things! I am still looking for the chat, but realize where I went wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: @Catomic . For my message on chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29386707#29386707   Pinged you but if you've never been before won't see you've been pinged.