# Qui, Qu' and Que

Tags: grammaire, interrogative

Hello fellow members of French StackExchange,
I am a beginner DELF A2 French learner and am having trouble with qui, qu' and que. I do understand the basic concept but am having trouble putting them into use into a real sentence.

For example, here is one of the questions I am doing.

Quel est l'appareil technologique le moins utile ____ tu as acheté? (qui, qu' or que goes into the blank)

For this question I am 100% sure that is is not qu' because qu' is the same as que but for a word beginning with a vowel. However, I am not sure about the other two.

Thanks,
Henry

Comment: This question has already an answer [Utilisation de “qui” et “que"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/utilisation-de-qui-et-que).

Answer (score 1):

`Que` and `qui` are pronouns *that* replace someone or something (like "that" in this very sentence):

- `Que` is for something, and also for someone when it replaces the [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)) of the [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause).
- `Qui` is for someone when this someone is the [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar)) of the relative clause.

In your case, 2 possible approaches:

1. You ask yourself what the blank word replaces in the sentence. What did you buy? A device. Something. Hence: **que**, with no doubt.
2. You ask yourself what's the grammatical type of the object represented by the pronoun: here, it's an "object" (You bought XXX). So, again, no question: even if the object would have been a person, the answer is **que**.

As the pronoun replaces a thing + the grammatical type is "object", there are here two reasons for the answer to be **que**.

As a side note: about "que tu *as* acheté" in your sentence. I'm not 100% sure this is totally incorrect, but I'm pretty sure a better mode is "que tu *aies* acheté" (i.e. use the subjunctive). You may check a long debate on this [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/le-meilleur-seul-premier-dernier-le-plus-adjectif-qui-que-superlatif-mode.90421/?hl=fr).

Comment: L'indicatif est possible et correct mais moins fréquent que le superlatif. Voir [par exemple](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/434.html). [Une explication possible sur la différence](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/post169256.html#p169256). (Il me semble qu'il y a déjà eu une question à ce sujet sur F)L.