# Pronoun Relative (Pronom Relatif)

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

As I understand, Qui is used for the subject pronoun while Que is used for the object pronoun.

In this sentence from an instructor: "**J'aime tous les pâtisseries qui contiennent du chocolate**", why does she use qui if 'pâtisseries' is the object that contains chocolate?

Comment: Welcome to French Language Stack Exchange.  Does this answer your question? [Utilisation de "qui" et "que"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/utilisation-de-qui-et-que)

Comment: The sentence should have been *J'aime tout**es** les pâtisseries*. But this is not what your question is about. Your question is not about French language but about distinguishing grammatical subjects and objects, English and French (and a lot of other languages) identify grammatical objects the same way. You could read [that page](https://www.grammar.com/grammatical_object) to enlighten you.

Comment: Can les pâtisseries be both the subject and object?  Because in my mind 'je' is still the subject of the sentence.  J'(aime) => les pâtisseries (contiennent) => du chocolat

Comment: @user9142430 Yes. The smaller sentence "pastries contain chocolate" is nested in your main sentence. We call it a *complément du nom* and it complements the noun *pâtisseries*. It's introduced with qui instead of que here because that noun is the subject of that nested sentence.